# How to add image in Highcharts Title and subtitle

Tags: javascript, image, highcharts, title

I'm trying to add images in chart title using Highcharts.The image doesn't show up.There's no script error as well.I doubt whether highcharts support images in title or not.Any help would be appreciated.Thank you in advance.

Here's the fiddle for reference:  http://jsfiddle.net/LHSey/123/

```
chart.setTitle({
            text: "Testing" + " " + "../images/appendImage.png "
        }, {
            text: "This is a test"
        });
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to set `useHTML` to `true`, and insert your image as HTML:

```
chart.setTitle({
    useHTML: true,
    text: "Testing" + " " + "<img src='../images/appendImage.png' alt='' />"
}, {
    text: "This is a test"
});
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LHSey/126/)**.

Comment: while using useHTML to true in pie chart the title is not aligning properly.In addition to,if it's a resizable pie/donut chart,the title is not centering inside the chart.Can you please help me out to center the title text with image inside the donut chart?

here's my fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/LHSey/131/

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve displaying image in title without useHTML:true?