# How to add font awesome icon in the pie chart title using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to add properties icon in the title of pie chart

```
Highcharts.chart('prop_cat_chart', {
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie',
        },
        title: {
            // text: 'Property As Category'
            text: 'Properties'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.3f}%</b> ({point.y:,.0f} Units)',
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                },
                showInLegend: true
            }
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
                name: 'Category',
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: datalist,
                animation: true,
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function (event) {
                            window.location.href = site_url + "filterproperties/propertiesType/" + this.id;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
    });
```

[image]

Comment: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=40070

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add image in Highcharts Title and subtitle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817698/how-to-add-image-in-highcharts-title-and-subtitle)